# Azure combine metrics for alerting

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I'm looking for a way to set up alerts on a combination of platform-provided metrics, for example the Microsoft.ApiManagement/service namespace has EventHubTotalFailedEvents and EventHubTotalEvents, but I would prefer a success rate instead.
Is there a way to define derived metrics?